# Why does 'wilful' = 'willful' connote negativity?

Tags: etymology

[Definition 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wilful?q=wilful+) is negative. I'm guessing so is Definition 2, because of 'stubborn' and 'regardless of the consequences'.

`1.` I'm flummoxed: Why? Doesn't the noun **will** connote positivity (its etymology: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=will&allowed_in_frame=0)?

From http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=willful&searchmode=none:

> **wilful** = ...c.1200, "strong-willed," usually in a bad sense,...

`2.` What's the term for this phenomenon, where the noun is positive but the adjective is negative, and vice versa?

`3.` Are there other words subject to this paradox?

Comment: How about [ill will](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ill+will)? I don't think in actual use *will* has to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

The meanings of a word are not constrained by its origins any more than your character is determined by that of your ancestors. The fact that your great-great-grandfather was First Lord of the Admiralty and his brother a notorious pirate does not mean that you yourself are destined either for the Navy or the long drop, or even that you are bound to a seagoing career. In the same way, words develop in different directions as they grow older, and what a word meant a hundred or two hundred or two thousand years ago is irrelevant to present-day users, who have no knowledge of that earlier meaning. To argue otherwise is the [etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

So there is no "paradox" here. ***Today***, *will* has no necessary "positive" meaning.